# Непонятный отступ слева

Tags: html, css

Откуда взялся отступ слева перед словом Главная.
Cсылка на код https://jsfiddle.net/pzycwwty/8/
Html

```
    <header class="main-header">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <nav class="main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ИНФОРМАЦИЯ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">НОВОСТИ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ПРАЙС-ЛИСТ</a></li>
                    <li><a сlass="active" href="#">МАГАЗИН</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="user-block">
                <a class="login" href="#">Вход</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>`
```

Css

```
 body {
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family: "PT Sans Narrow";
     color:#000000;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin:0px;
 }

.container {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.main-header{
    height:72px;
    background-color:grey;
}

.main-nav{
    float:left;
    width:615px;
    height:15px;
}

.main-nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:43px;
}

.main-nav li:last-child {
    margin-right:0px;
}

.user-block{
    float:right;
    width:67px;
    height:15px;
}
```

В коде насколько я вижу, он нигде явно не задан.

Comment: У `ul` уберите `padding-left`.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. Почему он там вообще появился ? )

Comment: у каждого браузера есть стили по умолчанию, поэтому необходимо эти стили сбрасывать, т.е. переопределять. Как вариант http://cssreset.com

Comment: @soledar10 cпасибо за ответ )

Answer (score 2):

По умолчание идет отступ у списка - ul.

Как убрать:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, раз уже на то пошло, то по хорошему и margin тоже обнулить нужно.